# What are the guidelines for referencing products and/or businesses in posts?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[Should we close questions challenging specific ads?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280/should-we-close-questions-challenging-specific-ads) covers some of this but I'd like more input ( hypotheticals would be most helpful ).

For example...

> Does eating three (product name) a day
> really prolong life ?
>
> In this ad
> (1: link to ad) (2: company name and page
> link) claims eating three of their
> (3: product name and link) a day will
> prolong your life by forty-two years.
> Is there any evidence this is true ?

1. Links to ads are an obvious no-no.
   There are always exceptions, but
   for ad links I think the
   justification would need to be clad
   in beryllium.
2. Should the company page be linked
   directly or would a third-party link
   be preferred ( assuming good-faith
   on the neutrality/reliability of the
   third-party link) ? Maybe a
   Wikipedia entry ?
3. Would this be the same as (1) with a slightly lower standard of
   justification ?

Other considerations on the topic in general ?

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that these questions are, *if nothing else*, too localized unless the claim in question is part of a large, well-known marketing campaign... In which case, finding references to it shouldn't be difficult.

If you *really* have to resort to linking to the company's website to prove that they made such a claim, you're screwed anyway - what happens when they update their site and the claim is suddenly nowhere to be found?

So if you just *gotta* ask, "Do things really go better with Coke?" you'll have a million references in the first Google search affirming that this claim was actually made.

If you feel the need need to get verification that *Spammer Bob's All N47Ur4L Herbal V14GR4* really does cure cancer like that email said... You can post the claim itself and describe what the product *is* without linking to it or including the full ad copy.

> Other considerations on the topic in general ?

Both the hypothetical examples I've given, and the *actual* example you reference, border on ridiculous. I wouldn't give any of them the benefit of the doubt, even without links, unless there was also indication that someone, somewhere, actually *believed* this. A report about folks that pour Coke on their breakfast cereal, or eschew chemo in favor of Bob's remedy, or religiously spread cream on their wrinkled, weathered faces. I mean... They're *ads* - all else being equal, you really shouldn't believe them *for that reason alone*.

Also, Drink Coke.

Comment: And eat bacon!!!

Comment: @Sklivvz No man. You know I don't dig on swine.