# Are claims made by product advertisements on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I saw [Do Tide Pods laundry detergent have 10 times the cleaning power of other liquid bargain brands?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40478/do-tide-pods-laundry-detergent-have-10-times-the-cleaning-power-of-other-liquid) and it got me thinking about this. As is the case in that question, advertisements making dramatic claims tend to do so with subjective and ambiguous terminology.

Comment: Is this a question? Or a statement?

Comment: @Jamiec I had already stated the question in the title; the body is what led to the question.

Comment: ha... right you are. Sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Questions about shopping: are they on-topic?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/921/questions-about-shopping-are-they-on-topic)

Comment: @Qsigma I thunk you're right, that looks like more or less the same question to me.